# What CLI allows me to add a printer to cups and see supply levels (toner/ink levels)?

Tags: 22.04, printing

I'm attempting to add a printer using cups via `lpadmin` using either the "everywhere" driverless option with a `ipp:// address`, or an `ldp:// address` with a generic postscript driver, and have even tried `-o cupsIPPSupplies=true`, but I can't get the toner/ink supply levels to appear in the GUI.

Previously the printer was added and `/etc/cups/printers.conf` shows attribute "marker-colors", "marker-names", and "marker-types", but I can't reproduce this with lpadmin on another workstation.

Answer (score 2):

I had a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746753/how-to-modify-add-cups-printer-attributes-like-marker-colors-marker-levels-or) and finally I found out that `marker-levels` is automatically added to `/etc/cups/printers.conf` after the first print job has been done, not when the printer itself is added. PS The option `-o cupsIPPSupplies=true` has no effect regarding my tests. It seems `true` is already the default, which is confirmed through [this post](https://lists.cups.org/pipermail/cups/2019-May/074656.html):

> You can disable it per printer by setting cupsIPPSupplies keyword to
> False in their PPDs

Regarding your question to display those values in the GUI:
It seems there is no standardized usage of `marker-levels` and by that CUPS does not display those values in the GUI. But this is only an assumption.

Maybe you script yourself something which periodically updates the printer description and adds those levels as you need them.